# Java execute a JAR with parameters on a remote server

Tags: java, remote-server

I have a program that needs to execute commands on several servers. I did some local tests with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` and it worked just fine.

But once I want to execute remote commands it doesn't work. For example if I do

```
ssh user@10.20.30.40 'touch /tmp/hello.txt'
```

it works in my terminal. But it doesn't work in my Java program with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh user@10.20.30.40 'touch /tmp/hello.txt'");
```

Do you have a solution to execute remote commands in a simple `main.java` for test purposes (no need for logs and production security and all) ?

Thank you!

*Edit*: The goal is to execute a JAR with parameters like this (logs don't really matter but would be nicer):

```
ssh user@10.20.30.40 'java -jar -Dbroker-ip=10.20.30.41 -Dtopic=topic -Dpartition-number=32 -Dthread=8 -Dsource=/tmp/hour_moves /opt/Produce.jar  > /tmp/logThread1 &'
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the command into a bash script and call that?

Comment: Yes and it works. But I would like to do it without writing a file on local server if possible.

Comment: I meant running something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myscript.sh'");`?  exec() is wierd on Java.  I always go back to this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: Well, to run this command you need to write the "myscript.sh" localy. I agree that exec() seems weird...

Answer (score 1):

Your command string must be split into a command array before it can be executed. At the terminal this will be done by a shell. Single quote characters have special meaning for the shell. The command array will look like this:

```
cmdarray[0] = "ssh";
cmdarray[1] = "user@10.20.30.40";
cmdarray[2] = "touch /tmp/hello.txt";
```

Your version of `exec()` uses another string tokenizer, splitting the string at whitespace characters. Now the command array looks like this:

```
cmdarray[0] = "ssh";
cmdarray[1] = "user@10.20.30.40";
cmdarray[2] = "'touch";
cmdarray[3] = "/tmp/hello.txt'";
```

So the executable `'touch` can't be found on the remote server.

BTW: there is no need to use single quotes. This should work too (in both cases):

```
ssh user@10.20.30.40 touch /tmp/hello.txt
```

Other special shell characters like `>` or `&` must be escaped at the terminal to be passed to the remote site (not interpreted by the shell but passed as argument of the ssh command). If you use `exec()` you don't have to escape this characters.

Be aware of the return type of `exec()`: it is a `Process` object. It is better to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...).waitFor();
```

to be sure the command has been finished.